# How to split and set data to listview in android?

Tags: android

I have a string in android.

```
str = |test1:23|st1:4|st2:3|st3:5|test2:25|st1:5|st2:6|st3:7|test3:26|st1:5|st2:2|st3:8|test4:28|st1:8|st2:3|st3:2|test5:29|st1:1|st2:2|st3:2|......

I need to split that string and set each data to listview in android.

I mean for each listitem I should keep the data as

test1:23
st1:4
st2:3
st3:5
---------------------
test2:25
st1:5
st2:6
st3:7
----------------------
```

Now I will split the string with | symbol using:

```
 String splitstring = str.split("\\|");
```

Now `splitstring[0]` contains `test1:23`, `splitstring[1]` contains `sty:4`. But I need to set first 4 to 1st listitem,the next four to next listitem and so on.
Please suggest me how can achieve that task? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
    String str = "test1:23|st1:4|st2:3|st3:5|test2:25|st1:5|st2:6|st3:7|test3:26|st1:5|st2:2|st3:8|test4:28|st1:8|st2:3|st3:2|test5:29|st1:1|st2:2|st3:2";
    String[] splitted = str.split("\\|");
    List<String> fourItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    int listItemPosition = 0;
    for (String s : splitted) {
        fourItems.add(s);
        if (fourItems.size()==4) {
            processItems(fourItems, listItemPosition++);
            fourItems.clear();
        }
    }

    private void processItems(List<String> fourItems, int position) {
        // do whatever you want to do with your four strings like
        // assigning it to your list item at position
    }
```

Of course this is wthout any error handling and the like